# Xamarin Forms - attempt to dismiss modal view controller whose view does not currently appear

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.auth

I am using Xamarin.Auth using Xamarin Forms.
On IOS, When Auth Completion event fired and I got access tocken ,

I need to Pop the current Page and need to push another

```
                    await  navigation.PopModalAsync();

                    if(IsAuthenticated)
                    {
                        await navigation.PushModalAsync (new Handshake.Shared.Pages.TemplateSelectionPage());                       
                    }
                    else
                        await navigation.PushModalAsync (new Handshake.Shared.Pages.LoginPage());
```

I got this error in Application Output :

```
attempt to dismiss modal view controller whose view does not currently appear. self = <Xamarin_Forms_Platform_iOS_PlatformRenderer: 0x7c7b3de0> modalViewController = <Xamarin_Forms_Platform_iOS_ModalWrapper: 0x7c7bb310>
```

Comment: On Android it is working...

Comment: How are you presenting the modal view?